# tt_news - How to add comments in tt_news single view?

Tags: plugins, typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I setup my own tt_news template and currently try to use the "comments" plugin. After installing and import the standard plugin constants it should show the comments automaticly (so I've read it). But no. Nothing.

How do I get the comments into my tt_news single template?

Answer (score 0):

you also have to insert the comments plugin on the news single page, below the news plugin with single view.

Here you can read about this in the extension manual:
[comments manual in TER](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/comments/1.7.1/#inserting-comments-on-a-page)

Regards
Patrick

Comment: According to documentation, this only adds number of comments not the plugin itself.

Comment: @MatejSvajger: for this feature you have to add another marker to the tt_news template.
But for showing the comments plugin you have to insert the plugin on the news single page (by backend or by typoscript), no changes in the tt_news template file.